# Когда стоит объявлять функцию как метод класса?

Tags: функции

Пусть, есть функция `len()`, которая считает длину чего бы то ни было. Это может быть строка, массив или что-то ещё. Часто это ряд специфических объектов из предметной области, у которых есть длина. Стоит выбор реализовывать её как метод каждого из объектов или объявить ее просто функцией.

Интуитивно понятно, что если свойство есть у всех объектов, то логичнее было бы задуматься о наиболее обобщенном подходе подсчета этого свойства, если это возможно, и создать просто функцию, которая будет считать его. Существуют ли какие-то общеизвестные практики проектирования архитектуры в таких ситуациях? Стоит ли вообще смешивать ОО и процедурный стиль? Если да, то в каких ситуациях это позволительно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Стоит ли вообще смешивать ОО и процедурный стиль?

Нет, ни в коем разе. В ОО "просто функции", у которых нет привзяанного состояния, заменяются статическими методами, и, таким образом, как минимум логически группируются. Я, впрочем, против статических методов (пушо статичные вызовы в коде хардкодят конкретную реализацию), и призываю такие штуки реализовывать обычными методами, просто вызывать их на единственном созданном объекте.

> Стоит выбор, реализовывать её как метод каждого из объектов или объявить ее просто функцией.

Это зависит от конкретного применения. Если это часть функционала шаблонизатора (например, фильтр length в Twig), то объекты ничего об этом не должны знать. Строка и коллекция же должны по-хорошему уметь возвращать свою длину самостоятельно, другое дело, что эти методы не будут никак взаимосвязаны. Если же вам нужен стандартизованный интерфейс доступа к объектам, то вам и нужен непосредственно интерфейс:

```
LengthExportingCapableInterface { // дурацкое название, конечно
    public int getLength();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Одну функцию len на все случаи жизни написать сложно. Если бы это было можно, она была бы давно написана.

Если такая функция существовала бы, то она должна была бы знать о устройстве всех классов и типов, в том числе ещё и ненаписанных. А это противоречие.

Если же Вы пишете функцию под себя, то смотрите на ее внутренности. Если там начинает появляться switch или серия if, которые проверяют тип и вызывают специфический код в каждом случае, то это уже явно плохой дизайн.

Как пример, можно посмотреть на STL из с++. Там сейчас есть функции begin и end, которые перекрывают аналогичные функции класса. В некоторых случаях это может быть сильно удобно (например, если нужно писать сильно шаблонизированный код).

> Интуитивно понятно, что если свойство есть у всех объектов, то логичнее было бы задуматься о наиболее обобщенном подходе подсчета этого свойства

Вот руки есть не только у людей, а и животных, почему же попытка пришить руки от горилы человеку обречена на провал? :)

> Существуют ли какие-то общеизвестные практики проектирования архитектуры в таких ситуациях?

Да, есть. Называется "не плоди сущностный без необходимости". Классу нужен len? Напишите. Ещё одному - напишите. Третьему нужен? Посмотрите, может, можно вынести кусок кода в отдельный родительский класс или функцию. Возможно, эта функция понадобится трем-четырем классам, а ту абстракцию, которую хочется навернуть, займет сотни строк кода.

> Стоит ли вообще смешивать ОО и процедурный стиль?

- в некоторых языках сложно смешать, например, в Java или С. Но некоторые умудряются;
- если Вам нужна одна маленькая функция в случае процедурного стиля и десять классов в случае ООП, берите процедурный подход;
- "проект горит", "критическая уязвимость", "нужно исправить месяц назад" - в этом случае любой код хороший, главное быстро и оперативно закрыть. Украсить код, возможно, получится позже.

Answer (score 0):

Тут имеет смысл обратить внимание на вот какую фразу в вашем вопросе:

> есть функция len(), которая считает длину чего бы то ни было

если это действительно некая одна универсальная функция, которая может считать длину  чего угодно, то она, по всей вероятности, представляет собой образец ужасного говнокода - вполне очевидно, что для разных сущностей вычисление вроде бы одинаковых данных (в частности, длины) будет выполняться различными способами. Поэтому такая универсальная функция будет либо иметь в качестве тела либо какой-то несусветных размеров **switch**, в каждой ветке которого будет обрабатываться вычисление длины для каждого конкретного типа (и все равно по понятным причинам все типы не будут охвачены), либо будет возвращать что-то невразумительное и малополезное типа размера указателя на этот тип данных. Следовательно, раз конкретный алгоритм вычисления длины зависит от конкретного типа,  то либо нужно будет плодить миллион перегрузок для функции **len** для каждого типа данных, либо имеет смысл поместить функцию в интерфейс и заставить каждый конкретный класс, длина которого нас интересует, реализовывать этот интерфейс. Это будет вполне разумно, поскольку именно конкретный тип данных в этом случае станет отвечать за особенности конкретной реализации этой функции.